# How to detect/convert a Multiframe image to single frame image in java/javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, image, web, multimedia

1 of our external API's doesn't allow Multiframe images.

So, There is a need to detect and convert a multiframe image to single frame image.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Askanode :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Also I need solution for this.